# Can one recover the content of an indexed Apache Lucene field

Tags: lucene

I am indexing String entities in Apache Lucene. E.g.

```
doc.add(new StringField(fieldNameSecret, fieldValueSecret, Field.Store.NO));
doc.add(new StringField(fieldNameMeta, fieldValueMeta, Field.Store.YES));
```

I want useres to be able to search for `fieldNameSecret` and return `fieldNameMeta`. 
As the content of `fieldValueSecret` is sensible my question is: is it possible to reconstruct/restore the content of `fieldValueSecret`?

Comment: As per niqueco's answer, generally yes, with some caveats. In your particular case, you are using a Stringfield, so unequivocally yes. The full content of the field is being indexed without analysis, so you wouldn't need to reconstruct anything, you could simply read them.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the field content can be restored, how much will depend on the indexing options used.

- Individual terms will be stored, and their presence in a particular field value will be exposed.
- Stemming will mangle terms, so if stemming removes plurals then the reconstructed value will not show a plural. Similarly, if you apply a `LowerCaseFilter` the original case could not be reconstructed.
- If you index with `IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS` somebody will be able to tell how many times a term has been mentioned.
- If you index with `IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS` somebody will be able to reconstruct the ordering of terms (however he won't be able to see things discarded during analysis, like punctuation).

ADDED: As mentioned by femtoRgon in the particular case of `StringField` you are explicitly asking Lucene to treat the whole field value as a single term, with no other processing. That will always expose the field value, because terms are stored (as mentioned in my first point above).